# Is the order of dataclasses.fields guaranteed?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Suppose I have a dataclass like

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
    a: int = 0
    b: std = ''
```

the order is relavent for example for the automatically defined constructor. So, when getting the diefferent fields of the dataclass via [dataclass.fields(...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields), are the fields in the returned tuple guaranteed to be given in the same order as defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) states the following:

> The order of the fields in all of the generated methods is the order in which they appear in the class definition.

So the order of definition is used for the `fields` property, ordering, and other methods.